# Android Service versus Intent Service for connecting to multiple Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

My app connects to multiple SPP Bluetooth devices all of which stream data. There are four devices streaming, one at 250 Hz and the rest at 100 Hz. I want to put them in a `Service` but also want each device to run in a separate `Thread`. Each `Thread` must also connect to the SQLite database to insert data in real-time. The devices can connect for long periods and can disconnect at anytime and reconnect at anytime. Once started the app could be running for 24 hours or more and always looking for the availability of already paired devices.

The questions is: is it better performance-wise to do this in a separate `Service` running multiple `Thread`s (a `Thread` for each connecting device) or is is better to run a separate `IntentService` (which will of course runs in its own worker `Thread`?

I have read many other questions and answers in SO and elsewhere about this and can see the advantages and disadvantages of each approach but I cannot find an answer that specifically answers my question. I am not sure if running multiple `Thread`s in a `Service` will not still block the main `Thread` at times. On the other hand I do not think I can run multiple `Thread`s in an `IntentService` at the same time.

Comment: Even when using IntentService you need to launch background threads since IntentService uses one background thread to handle all the requests

Comment: Why not wait until someone answers the [first copy of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870810/running-multiple-services-on-android-for-bluetooth-devices)?

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your reply. I am still uncertain about the advantages of running the IntentService since it queues and does not process in parallel, at least that is what I understand.

Comment: @323go I know that it looks like they are the same but they are actually different. The first is really talking about running multiple services, one for HDP and one for SPP. This question is referring to the implementation of just the SPP side but I agree there is overlap and perhaps I should have waited. In this question I am really trying to see if it is better to use the IntentService than the Service for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your intended scenario, `IntentService` is not a bad idea, but not in the way you are proposing. Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.
>
> This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks
>   from an application's main thread. The IntentService class exists to
>   simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics. To use it,
>   extend IntentService and implement onHandleIntent(Intent).
>   IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and
>   stop the service as appropriate.
>
> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

So, launching an `IntentService` for each bluetooth device would mean one or the other would be blocked. Whenever I communicate with multiple sockets (devices), I assign a thread to each socket... this thread is then responsible for connecting to, communicating with, and reconnecting to the socket as necessary. This pattern is the same used in any server program: There's a ClientThread for each connection, which gets spawned by the connection listener.

However, there's a good place for an `IntentService` as well: It's great to deliver the data to you sqlite database. Place the datum in an intent, send it to your `IntentService`, and it will open the database (possibly even start a transaction) when it needs to, then post all data, and when it runs out of work, commits the transaction and closes the database. A lot of the necessary plumbing for that is provided by the API.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. My original design had multiple threads for the device sockets but was running in the main activity, which I gather is not the best implementation. So, I am moving the connecting etc to a Service or IntentService. When you say that you assign a thread to each socket do you mean within an IntentService? Thanks again!

Comment: So basically IntentService would be used over service when we receive concrete intent with information package like in bundle.

Comment: @kuba, just like the documentation says, `IntentService` is usually used for one-shot tasks that need to be done in the background, but might take a while. There's no reason you can't pass information to a `Service` using a binder.